# How to create a method to return the number of drinks of each product using an arraylist?

Tags: java, sorting, object, arraylist

I'm a beginner and I have no clue how to access my established arraylist to be able to return the number of drinks for each product (eg. 4 Cokes)

P.S. the product is the name of my other class.

Here's my code so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList; 

public class VendingMachine {

  ArrayList <Product> vending = new ArrayList <Product> ();



public  VendingMachine(int maxType, int quantity) {

    int maxCap= maxType*quantity; 
    vending = new ArrayList <Product> (maxCap); 
}

//Initialize the number & quantity of the products 

 public ArrayList <Product> initialize () {

    for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
        Product coke = new Product("Coke", 1.30, 230, 350, false); 
        vending.add(coke); 
    }

    for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
        Product pepsi = new Product("Pepsi", 1.10, 240, 350, false); 
        vending.add(pepsi); 
    }

    for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
        Product gingerAle = new Product("GingerAle", 1.30, 210, 320, false); 
        vending.add(gingerAle); 
    }

    for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
        Product dietCoke = new Product("DietCoke", 1.50, 200, 310, true); 
        vending.add(dietCoke); 
    }

    for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
        Product dietPepsi = new Product("DietPepsi", 1.40, 190, 320, true); 
        vending.add(dietPepsi); 
    }   
    return vending;     
}
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Java but isn't ArrayList vending a part of your VendingMachine class? If so, can't you iterate through VendingMachine.vending and count the number of the product names? Like a for loop that goes through each product and checks product.name against some parameter and if it's true it increments some counter?

Comment: Thank you for commenting! I've have tried just that but it keeps showing me errors and not letting me use iterate.

Comment: Can you show us your iteration code?

Comment: What is the `Product` class? Should it have a "quantity" field instead of just creating multiple instances of each identical product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might help. Try this see what you get. Implement as a method of VendingMachine class.

```
public int getProductCount(String pName) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    int count = 0;

    if (pName == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    for (Product item : this.vending) {
        //Assuming the instance variable of your Product class is called name
        //Also assuming name is private and you have a getter method in your Product class
        if (item.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(pName)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It really really helped!!